# how to print just the popup window

Tags: drupal, printing, popup

Using our custom Drupal module to display tabular information pulled via another server's view (so it's not saved to drupal db).

Users click a line item in this table, which causes a shadowboxed popup modal window containing that line item's details. We are using the popups api function call to achieve this:

```
popups_add_popups()
```

Unfortunately printing prints everything, including overriding normal print css to not print logo. The grayed out window and popup get printed.

What we want is to include an obvious printer icon in the popup, and when users click the icon only that popup is sent to print.

I've seen

```
@media print {
  .noprint {
    display:none
  }
}
```

But I don't like that because we would have to override the normal printing css. Would rather a solution to just print our popup.

Seems like a perfect question for stackoverflow community. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full-fledged answer as I never implemented myself this type of functionality, but I would look into using jQuery in this case, because - if I got you correctly - the popup you are using is not a real browser window but a superimposed `<div>` that gets populated and displayed on click. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

I did not really dig into it, but if what above is right, than you might be interested in having a look to [jPrintArea](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPrintArea):

> jPrintArea is a small jquery plugin to print only contents of a specified element.

HTH!